# iOS app wrapper for jquery mobile site with file upload

Tags: iphone, ios, mobile, jquery-mobile, cordova

I have created a mobile version of my website using jquery mobile. My site requires alot of image upload facilities (pretty important for the site). I was wondering if there was a way to create an ios app from the jquery mobile site. Here is the idea:

1. app is bascially a web browser
2. app loads the mobile version of my site
3. app replaces any 'file' fields found in the jquery mobile site with a usable photo browser/camera button.

This means that I won't need to build a entirely seperate mobile app to work with my site and when I update the jquery mobile source, it automatically updates the source that the ios app accesses.

I'm open to any suggestions. I am wondering if maybe phonegap has a way of doing this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible, but won't get approved into the app store since it depends on loading your mobile site, the solution would be to take your mobile site and build it in phonegap. You can load external images, but try not to do too much of that because it will again not be approved.

If you do wrap your mobile site files in phonegap you should be good to go, you can still access data online, but use ajax calls to get that information, and also be sure to have an option for users who don't have an internet connection - Twitter and Facebook and apps like that come with the assumption that all content depends on a connection, but other apps that isn't implied and can cause rejection unless you have error checking for connection.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Well...what about making a phongap app that fetches the HTML of a particular URL? Pretty much the same thing...would that be allowed?

Comment: You can fetch parts of the app from online, but not the whole thing. The idea with phonegap is to allow you develop with js, html and css and have access to the native features. I would say have the app come with the UI and you can load the content in, but just be careful that the app isn't just loading an external site.